# Generic function to test if a position hits on a circle given a direction

Tags: geometry

I am looking for a function that given `start angle, end angle, moving clockwise or anticlockwise, hitting angle` and will return if such a movement hits the `hitting angle` or not.

So for example, if we move from 270 degrees to 50 degrees in a clockwise direction, it will hit the `hitting angle = 0 or 360` degree position, but it will not hit if we move in an anticlockwise direction.

Another example is that if we move from 80 degrees to 100 degrees clockwise, it will hit `hitting angle = 90` but not in a anticlockwise direction.

Comment: Are you restricting your angles to 0<=theta<=360? Otherwise you need to think about whether going from 0 to 420 you hit everything or not. Also, I guess you are thinking of your angles increasing clockwise. Math types would not use that convention. We would start at 0 on the positive x-axis, then increase ccw up to 90 on the pos. y axis. So going from 80 to 100 clockwise, I would want to say you do not hit 90. But basically you want to test if your starting angle is less than your finishing angle, and if your hit is between them and if ccw or cw. Handle the 8 cases. Refactor later.

Comment: Side note: Generic in C# has special meaning- make sure to clarify if you really need generic or just used this word for fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't really need to explicitly pass the direction of travel. You just need a way to specify a particular arc of angle. So you can just adopt the convention that the angle should increase as it moves from the start to the end angle. To specify the inverse of an arc, just pass the start and end in reverse order.

So, let's define a function that works if the angles are in order from 0 to 360 degrees - no modulo required:

```
bool IsBetween(int low, int high, int target)
{
    return (target >= low && target <= high);
}
```

That will work only if `low` is not larger than `high`. If it is (because the angle is sweeping across the 360 degree line), then we can just split the arc into two sections, one from the start angle to 360, and one from 0 to the finish angle.

```
bool SweepHits(int start, int finish, int target) 
{
    // check for the simple case
    if (start <= finish) return IsBetween(start, finish, target);

    // straddling 360 degrees - break into two sections
    return IsBetween(start, 360, target) || IsBetween(0, finish, target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, I think your initial examples are maybe wrong? If we start at 270 degrees and proceed to 50 going clockwise, we will NOT hit 0 degrees (same if you move from 80 to 100 degrees clockwise, you won't hit 90 degrees.  This answer assumes that is a mistake on your part.

To clarify, this answer has angles starting from 0 degrees and going to 360 degrees counterclockwise.

UPDATED:
This now works regardless of whether the start angle is less or more than the end angle.

```
public static bool DidWeHitAngle(double hittingAngle, double startAngle, double endAngle, bool clockwise)
    {
        var minAngle = Math.Min(startAngle, endAngle);
        var maxAngle = Math.Max(startAngle, endAngle);
        var dir = minAngle == startAngle ? clockwise : !clockwise;
        if (hittingAngle < minAngle || hittingAngle > maxAngle)
        {
            if (dir)
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!dir)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```